# Windows: Can I set the folder where iTunes backs up my iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup, windows

I have a PC running Windows 10 with 2 Hard drives.

1. **C:** smaller SSD which runs windows and Office
2. **D:** large (2 TB) SATA that stores all my data.

When iTunes backs up my iPhone to my PC, it will default to **C:** under the Users folder. Is there a way to set it to do the backups to somewhere on my **D:** drive? I don't see any option there. I have **D:** set for my library, but I know that's different. I'm okay with manually setting the registry if needed, but hoping for a more legitimate route in case I need a restore later.